# Changing EditText's value blocks the keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/others"
        android:id="@+id/input_others" />
    <EditText
        android:minEms="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/number_input_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/number_input_padding"
        android:id="@+id/input_others_number"
        android:text="@string/others_default"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

If the user touches the EditText, the checkbox should be checked, and its value should be removed:

```
final CheckBox othersButton = findViewById(R.id.input_others);
final EditText othersNumber = findViewById(R.id.input_others_number);
othersNumber.setOnFocusChangeListener((view, hasFocus) -> {
    if (hasFocus) {
        othersButton.setChecked(true);
        othersNumber.setText("");
    }
});
```

The problem is that if I touch the EditText, although it gets focus (bottom line color becomes different), the keyboard doesn't appear (only for the 2nd touch). But if I remove the line `othersNumber.setText("");`, the keyboard comes up for the 1st touch fine.

Why is it happening, and how should I fix it? I know I can force the keyboard to appear, but I don't think that is needed here.

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside if (hasFocus):

```
((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(othersNumber, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

So it looks like this:

```
     if (hasFocus) {
         othersButton.setChecked(true);
         othersNumber.setText("");

((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(othersNumber, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);

}
```

The keyboard will come up on the first tap.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this isn't what I'm looking for. I've already added this to my code to force the keyboard to appear temporarily. But normally this is not a good solution. Maybe I misunderstand how those things work.